# ContextMenu causes memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I've spent the last few days trying to track down a memory leak in my WPF application and I think I've nailed it to the ContextMenu.

If the user opens the context menu (in my application this is required to remove the view/viewModel so always happens before deletion) then even after all references to the ViewModel are removed, and the View is no longer in the VisualTree, the objects retain some references in the memory profiler and the data is not released - causing my memory leak.

I've made a small example containing a ViewModel ExampleViewModel:

```
public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

With a nice simple view & contextMenu:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContextMenuMemoryLeak.ExampleView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenuMemoryLeak"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="Text"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

The window adds and removes these to an ObservableCollection:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ExampleViewModel>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ExampleViewModel> viewModels;
    public ObservableCollection<ExampleViewModel> ViewModels
    {
        get { return viewModels; }
        set {
            viewModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ViewModels");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ViewModels.Add(new ExampleViewModel { Name = $"Item {i}" });
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModels.Clear();
    }
}
```

And displays them:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuMemoryLeak.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenuMemoryLeak"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Add More</Button>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1">Remove All</Button>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ExampleView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I take a snapshot in the memory profiler after adding some ExampleViewModels, and then after deleting them again I get nice behaviour. The 10 classes are removed cleanly as they're not referenced anywhere:

[image]

However, now I'll re-add the 10. Then I'll right click on 5 of them (opening a context menu) and then delete them all:

[image]

The 5 View and ViewModels I opened a context menu on stick around... indefinitely!

I'm really surprised that I managed to make this happen in such a simple example (I was sure it was some crazy way I was doing bindings in context menus or something) as surely I would be able to google a similar problem if this is so general to all context menus... It seems not though as I can't seem to find many/any references to this issue on google.

Any ideas on how to solve it? Do I have to dispose of context menus?

**Edit:** When I check the "Path's to root" on the ViewModel that's retained, the results are a popup, and under that the context menu in question:

[image]

However, sometimes it has more:

[image]

The view is referenced in a few UI components, but I can't seem to find anything interesting in there (Though it appears if I remove the binding, the view DOES get destroyed!):

[image]

Comment: +1 for minimizing the code. What does WinDbg + SOS `!gcroot` say? Other than that: you right-click on a context menu ... in order to open the context menu for the context menu entry?

Comment: Not tried any other profilers yet - will have a look at those. And I was trying to say right click on the ExampleView's Grid to open the ContextMenu, thus showing the TextBlock "Text" in a popup.

Comment: It would be good to know what reference is holding these 5 remaining objects, can your profiler show that? (some of profilers surely can)

Comment: I've added the "paths to root" for the Vew and VewModel, which I believe are the references preventing GC

Comment: Could you also confirm that the same behavior ocurs when you are not using textbox in your context menu and viewmodel? If you change that to be a TextBlock is behavior still the same?

Comment: I was trying to simplify the View, and have changed it to a grid (with size and background so I can right click) and have found without the binding the View is correctly removed - however the ViewModel is still retained with it's reference to the Popup/ContextMenu. I suspect the binding is retaining the View when the ViewModel is retained by the popup?

Comment: Well, from what I've been recently [reading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications/) about memory leaks in WPF, the bindings could cause leaks when they are binded to nor DependencyObject, nor INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. In your case I don't see why binding itself could provoke a leak.

Comment: I've also been reading about that. I was wondering if the weak reference of the binding would show in the profiler as a reference if the referenced object (ViewModel) was held elsewhere, i.e. by the context menu.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no binding error in your output window ?

Comment: @Versatile, I can confirm there's no binding errors - and it occurs even with no binding it seems.

Comment: Why are you binding the DataContext on each item? The DataContext property should be automatically set to the object that the ListBox is creating a view for. Overriding this with a binding seems unnecessary and will cause a two-way reference between the objects.